# How do you export a temporal KML from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kml, spatio-temporal-data

If I have data with a timestamp attribute, how do I export that from QGIS into a time-aware KML that invokes the GoogleEarth time slider?

I do not see any sort of options in the **Save vector layer as** dialogue and internet searches have turned up zero.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [KML Reference Errata](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#TimeStamp), timestamp and timespan must be modified in the raw XML. [Google's KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#timespan) guide gives more information on its syntax and examples of its usage.

However, I would add that Google Earth Pro supports uploading of shapefiles as well. Provided that your attribute table has a properly formatted time/date field, it usually shows the time slider automatically when the layer is selected. If your data already has the timestamp values, you may want to try that instead.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am aware of the KML documentation; my question had to do specifically with QGIS and whether it supports the KML time tags. At this point I'm guessing the answer is: "it doesn't."

Comment: I suppose not. Though it probably wouldn't be too difficult to make a tool that uses ogr2ogr to accomplish this. I'll keep looking into this, could be a potential plugin worth sharing.